# Run javascript for loop on delay

Tags: javascript

On my page I'm using MaxMind to populate a users long/lat.

I'm also using a script (containing the haversine formula) to take the users long/lat and assign a distance parameter to an object that relates to a store location.

Once the distance has been stored I want to run the following loop

```
for(i=0; i<cities.length; i++){
    var newLat = cities[i].lat;
    var newLon = cities[i].lon;
    getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(userLat,userLon,newLat,newLon);
    var lowest = 1000
    if(cities[i].distance< lowest){lowest = cities[i].distance}
}

    cities.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.distance - b.distance;
    })[0]
        var div = document.getElementById('test');
            if(cities[0].fax == null){
                div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + cities[0].street + '<br />' + cities[0].city + '<br />' + cities[0].postal + '<br /><b>Phone:</b>' + cities[0].phone;
            }else{div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + cities[0].street + '<br />' + cities[0].city + '<br />' + cities[0].postal + '<br /><b>Phone:</b>' + cities[0].phone + '<br /><b>Fax:</b>' + cities[0].fax;

            }
```

The only thing is that since there's a delay on the coordinates showing up, the loop can't run right away.
How can I run this loop after the coordinates are populated?

Comment: Can you share the code which is getting the latitude and longitude? You can have a construct where you wrap the for loop inside the functionality of getting the latitude.. by saying something like

if lat and long = actual values, { for loop }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setTimeout` function, eg.:

```
setTimeout(function () { yourCode... }, 5000);
```

However, that is rarely the proper solution. Instead, you should look in the API of your data source, it probably has a callback function you can use to get notified of the data being available. That's the proper way to wait for data. If there's no such way, you'll have to use `setTimeout` (in fact, call it again if data isn't available yet when you get inside the delayed code).

Comment: I'll take a look at the docs, but this works great for what I need. Thanks!